# How to read PPP$ aloud?

Tags: purchasing-power-partity

> How to read PPP$ aloud?

That is in a paper that I should read loud in a presentation, but I don't know the most

Is it "purchasing power parity in US Dollar,"

or "purchasing power parity in terms of US Dollar,"

or ... ?

Comment: Either will be understood, though I might say *Dollars* in both cases.  You could also say "In US Dollars at purchasing power parity"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about linguistics than economics.

Comment: @BBKing I asked this question in the English Language Learners, and some persons, like you, close-voted it saying that it is more about economics!

Comment: @Henry So how would you say "the budget is 3000M PPP$"?

Comment: Both versions you mentioned seem fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary to stress that these figures are pegged to the *US* dollar. A PPP dollar is a dollar in its own right. Thus, simply saying "The budget is three billion purchasing power parity dollars" is good. Mentioning PPP in the context of a US project is unnecessary.

The World Bank uses the phrase "international dollars" on [its data portal](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/PA.NUS.PPP), so you can say "international dollars" if you are willing to explain what that means to anyone unfamiliar with that phrase. That phrase has the advantage that it is shorter, so it is less cumbersome to say out loud.