# How to calculate PPP$ from LCUs?

Tags: exchange-rates, poverty, purchasing-power-partity

Is there one single formula which allows to calculate the income of a person in [PPP\$](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/27144/how-to-read-ppp-aloud?rq=1) from her income in LCUs (local currency units), given for example the  [PPP conversion factor, GDP (LCU per international $)](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/PA.NUS.PPP) as published by the World Bank.

Assume for example an Indian farmer with a monthly income of ₹50,000, given India's PPP conversion factor of 18 and exchange rate ₹70 = $1. What is his monthly income in PPP\$ and by which formula? Is other or further information needed?

Vice versa: What is the farmer's monthly income in rupees when his income is known to be PPP\$30?

---

**References:**

- GapMinder's [Dollar Street](https://www.gapminder.org/dollar-street/matrix?countries=India)
- [Detailed income calculations for Dollar Street](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9jWD65HiLUnRm5ZNWlMSU5GNEU)
- [The Economic Lives of the Poor](https://economics.mit.edu/files/805) by Abhijit V. Banerjee and Esther Duflo

Answer (score 1):

It works like any other exchange rate:

- Divide ₹50,000 by 70 to get about US$714 / month at market exchange rates
- Divide ₹50,000 by 18 to get about PPP$2778 / month at PPP rates (so not a poor farmer)
- Multiply USD$30 by 70 to get ₹2100 at market exchange rates
- Multiply PPP$30 by 18 to get ₹540 at PPP rates

Comment: You are right: ₹50,000 is more than the average Indian farmer earns, this is more like ₹10,000 or ₹20,000 (with sideline jobs).

Comment: Nevertheless, this doesn't work: According to Gapminder's Dollar Street, PPP$30 is a somehow not atypical income of poor farmers, but ₹540 per month is an unrealistically low  income: not even the poorest farmers earn only such a small amount per month.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Let's take [the first example I came across from Gapminder](https://www.gapminder.org/dollar-street/family?place=557036781e788ebf3eb00f99) of a fruit collector and family in West Bengal with a monthly income of PPP$29 per adult so presumably about ₹520. Now take [the second case I found](https://www.gapminder.org/dollar-street/family?place=54b51a173755cbfb542c2473) of a farmer and family near Chennai with a monthly income of PPP$245 per adult so say about ₹4400 a month. Looking around their homes suggests different farmers can have very different incomes.